# Windsor WcfFacility: Setting ServiceBehavior properties

Tags: castle-windsor, wcffacility

I'm hosting a service using Windsor's WCF Facility, but I can't get `UseSynchronisationContext` and `ConcurrencyMode` set that one would normally do using the `ServiceBehaviorAttribute`. I've seen two options that apparently should work (but tried both to no avail):

1. Registering `ServiceBehaviorAttribute` as a Component for `IServiceBehavior`
2. Modifying the `Description` collection of `Behaviors` in the `OnCreated` configuration callback in the WCF registration.

A third method that I've tried is using `AddExtensions`, but that results in an exception because there's already a `ServiceBehaviorAttribute` (by default?) in the list of Behaviors. This is also the case with method 2, but in that case I can remove it and add a new one, or modify the existing entry.

It's really frustrating that there doesn't seem any documentation on this except a line stating 'Remove the ServiceBehaviorAttribute' from your services, apparently because it can conflict with the WcfFacility.

Can someone point me on how to properly do this? Any hint is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I didn't properly test. Modifying the properties of the `ServiceBehaviorAttribute` in the list of `Behaviors` of the `Description` property in the `OnCreated` action actually works as intended.

Sample registration:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IWCFWarehouseServiceAsyncCallback>()
    .ImplementedBy<WarehouseService>()
    .AsWcfService(new DefaultServiceModel()
        .AddBaseAddresses(baseAddress)
        .OnCreated(host =>
        {
            var sb = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>();
            sb.UseSynchronizationContext = false;
            sb.ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant;
        })
       .AddEndpoints(WcfEndpoint.BoundTo(binding).At("WarehouseService"))));
```